# Tailwindcss not working with next.js; what is wrong with the configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-purge

For some reason, `tailwind` is not rendering properly in next.js.

I'm wondering if something is wrong with my settings?

Styles folder - tailwind.css

@tailwind base;

```
/* Write your own custom base styles here */

/* Start purging... */
@tailwind components;
/* Stop purging. */

/* Write you own custom component styles here */
.btn-blue {
  @apply bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}

/* Start purging... */
@tailwind utilities;
/* Stop purging. */

/* Your own custom utilities */
```

....

_app.js

```
import React from "react";
// import "styles/global.scss";


import 'styles/tailwind.css'


import NavbarCustom from "components/Layout/NavbarCustom";
import Footer from "components/Layout/Footer";
import "util/analytics.js";
import { ProvideAuth } from "util/auth.js";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ProvideAuth>
      <>
        <NavbarCustom
          bg="white"
          variant="light"
          expand="md"
          logo="icons/Logo_512px.png"
        />

        <Component {...pageProps} />
```

What am I doing wrong? so confused, usually this sort of setup is fine.

This is the site btw - https://moodmap.app/ .

#### using the information below, made changes and still same issue weirdly.

https://moodmap.app/ is the site example.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
  },
  purge: ['./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'accent-1': '#333',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      'tailwindcss',
      'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
      [
        'postcss-preset-env',
        {
          autoprefixer: {
            flexbox: 'no-2009',
          },
          stage: 3,
          features: {
            'custom-properties': false,
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  }

{
  "name": "MoodMap",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [
    "MoodMap"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@analytics/google-analytics": "0.2.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.5.0",
    "analytics": "0.3.1",
    "fake-auth": "0.1.7",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "1.13.1",
    "next": "9.5.3",
    "query-string": "6.9.0",
    "raw-body": "^2.4.1",
    "rc-year-calendar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-hook-form": "4.10.1",
    "react-query": "2.12.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "stripe": "^8.52.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "stripe-webhook": "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/stripe-webhook"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.2.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.7.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.8.9"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I think your setup is too big. You can achieve this with much simpler stuff nowdays.

First, I don't think CSS needs to be loaded into nextjs anymore and modules are supported natively. (So you can delete this withCSS stuff)

Second, tailwind doesn't need such elaborate setup anymore, if you are using the newer versions.

So you will need to install postcss-preset-env, but it does remove the need for big config now.

Check out this example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss

Comment: Does your css import in _app.js work properly? Try to delete next.config.js as well :)

Comment: This is a non-answer. "Your setup is too complicated" is a useless opinion.

Comment: Readme is not giving complete information. Also what you have is the basic tailwind CSS. trying that is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 84):

In my case, I had set up the Tailwind config file correctly, but tailwind styles were not applying. Deleting the `.next` folder and running `next dev` helped.

Comment: Not sure why but this was it for me too. Thanks

Comment: I had to do that after rerunning `npx tailwindcss init` with the `-p` that I forgot the first time.

Comment: I deleted the `.next` folder, like above, then run `npm run dev`. That rebuilt the `.next` folder and all the Tailwind stuff started working. Thank you!!! @gaurav-thakur

Comment: I believe if you have ran npm run dev before adding tailwindcss than these are cached and don't load.

Comment: Thanks, this worked immediately.

Comment: thank you.  i was scratching my head over this.

Comment: works for me also ) thanks

Answer (score 83):

**For devs that created their project with nextJS.**

be aware that the content of the `tailwind.config.js` needs the correct paths to the files.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

For example, if you create a project with nextjs for example, you have a `pages` folder, where your `index.js` file is located. Therefore the code snippet (see below) on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss is not perfectly matching. Change it to the above or your own liking.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: You should also add your components folder to the content.

Comment: I forgot './src'

Comment: Missed this! thanks for this

Comment: Thank you for this. I forgot to check the tailwind config file.

Comment: You save my day: I have an ui/ folder next to the app/ and if so, I had to add the path for it ("./src/ui/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"). Obvious but it was blowing my mind ^^

Answer (score 68):

The same issue with my project, but I try to change the `globals.css` like this:

before

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

after

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import './base.css';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Comment: what about the `'/base.css';` ? is it another file or import from tailwind?

Comment: @NicoGulo your custom css

Comment: but my custom css is inside globals.css. should I move to the base.css?

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: worked for me thank you

Comment: I wonder why is `@tailwind` doens't work and `@import` does work?

Comment: this worked for me. can someone explain why this fixes it?

Comment: Looks like something has changed in newer version of tailwind.. I had made a project few months back and it was fine.. Today I created a new one this fix was required for it to work.

Comment: I got the same problem as OP. Tried AndriyFM's fix and it works. Then I tried a brand new `create-next-app` to see if the problem still persists. There's no problem. Then I went back to the previous project and replaced all `@import` rules with `@tailwind` rules. It still works. 

Considering that there's no such issue opened at Tailwind, I guess the problem has something to do with Next.js not purging properly.

Comment: @bytrangle I tried the exact same and it worked, maybe it's a bug on the next.js side?

Comment: But why the error with the path and qoute?

Answer (score 35):

I followed the official tutorial to install TailwindCSS into my NextJS app from here — https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs - but still couldn't get things working.

It turns out that I had forgotten to import `global.css` into my main app file.

Adding -

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
```

into _app.tsx solved it for me.

Comment: I didn't realize such a small thing. Thanks!

Comment: I migrated to the new `/app` directory and needed to add it to `app/layout.tsx`

Comment: Thank god this has 19 upvotes lol. Would've been a little worried about my life choices if it was only me lol.

Comment: Also, the relative path if you're using the page folder will be
`import "../app/globals.css";`
inside the index.tsx of your page folder. If you're using the default npx create-next-app

Comment: Thanks, I deleted all css related things in `layout.tsx` when start a new project and forgot to add `import "./globals.css"` back using app router.

Comment: Thank you so much for this one line great solution. I have spent around one hour and cursed nextjs a lot. finally, this line relaxed me. Thank you again....

Answer (score 17):

For me the solution was adding `./src/...` to content sources in `tailwind.config.js`. Official Next.JS + Tailwindcss example doesn't support src folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me since I had a separate directory for the components.

Answer (score 15):

Importing like this in the global.css resolved the issue for me:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Answer (score 13):

One of my projects had  those package versions installed

```
"next": "11.1.0",
"autoprefixer": "^10.3.3",
"postcss": "^8.3.6",
"tailwindcss": "^2.2.8"
```

this setting in `tailwind.config.js` was working:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Recently I started a new project with these packages:

```
"next": "12.0.8",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
"postcss": "^8.4.5",
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.15"
```

The previous config setting was not working. So I changed it to :

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: That last bit worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 8):

I got mine to work in the weirdest way after hours of fiddling with it; I just added a class to an element in one of my components and then wrote custom CSS for that class in the global.css file, then all tailwinds classes reflected. This might be a bug in tailwind's code that they need to trace and fix.

Comment: Please share a code example.

Comment: This worked for me; something similar to it did. I removed a style in globals.css, saved, then added it back. Tailwind then worked.

Comment: I did the same after trying and failing for more than a day and it worked like a charm, thank you.
In my **.tsx** file I did this: 
 `<p className='myclass'>Some text</p>`
and in my **global.css** file I did that:
```@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;  @layer { .myclass { @apply text-gray-600; }}```

Answer (score 8):

For people who are still having an issue with following versions:

```
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
"postcss": "^8.4.13",
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
```

in a Nx + Next.js environment, you can simply use following config files:

```
// postcss.config.js
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

---

```
// tailwind.config.js
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    join(__dirname, './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'),
    join(__dirname, './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: ah thank you very much, it solves my issue! I've used tailwind 1.1.4 and postcss-preset-env and I want to upgrade to tailwind with version 3, and it solved by looking for this.

Comment: This worked for me on the same versions. Thank you so much.

Comment: This solution worked though I am not using Nx. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I want to correct myself. I had pages and components in `src` folder and I just had to add `./src/` in `tailwind.config.js`. Thanks :)

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you. We are using NX and this was exactly what we need to get it sorted.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming to this in 2023, and none of the above solutions work, it might sound obvious, but you need to make sure you have a postcss.config.js file, even if it's just empty, in your Next.js app.

If you don't, the styles won't run. I spent a little while trying to figure this out, including deleting build folders etc.

If you follow the docs, you should have one already, but if you don't (or accidentally deleted it), you can either run this in your terminal:

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

**Important note about running init command above - it will overwrite your tailwind config. Make sure you take a copy of it before running the above.**

Or just create a postcss.config.js file in the root of your directory with following content:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: My hero, I'd gotten fat fingered before committing and drag/dropped a folder before a lunch break leading to a fair bit of confusion... Interesting there is no 404/real error! Thanks!

Comment: you sir deserves a shower of beers. thanks a lot for this. it feels utterly wrong that in 2023 such a dark error can still happen.

Comment: yeah i agree, such a weird little issue but figured it out eventually

Answer (score 5):

The issue for me was with a 'create-next-app' I did not have /pages/_app.js and therefore the global.css was not parsed.

Creating /pages/_app.js with the following content resolved the issue

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

Comment: FWIW, i just created with `create-next-app` and the file at `src/pages/_app.js` was created.

Answer (score 4):

I had just migrated my app from [`CRA`](https://create-react-app.dev/) to [`create-next-app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app). so my `CRA` App had a folder named `features` and under it was a folder for each feature was its `Redux` slicer and componentes, etc.

What solved it for me is to include the `features` folder in `tailwind.config.js`:

before:

```js
content: [
  "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
]
```

after

```js
content: [
  "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./features/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a _app.js file inside pages folder then add this code. The globals.css path should be correct.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me was creating the application via `npx create-next-app@latest` and opting in for the new src folder structure:

```
? Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? › No / Yes
```

If you select `Yes`, the following addition is required to the `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: This is what saved me hours of headache! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like a sane person's solution, but my solution came down to simply editing `globals.css`. There is nothing more specific about the solution to share.

I started with a completely fresh Next.js project and followed instructions to add Tailwind CSS. I tried all the solutions listed in this project.

- Used the example Next.js project creation script (worked)
- Copied and pasted each file from the example project
- Used the exact same versions
- Deleted `.next` and reinstalled all packages
- Used a variety of different ways to include Tailwind.

But the precise solution was this: I cut the contents of globals.css such that it only included the `@tailwind` directives (and some font `@import` directives above it), which suddenly activated Tailwind CSS. Pasting what I had just cut out maintained this newfound 'working' state.

I don't know how this could be, as there shouldn't be anything cached (I deleted the `.next` build folder) and I had been editing `globals.css` for other purposes (but I had not touched anything other than the tailwind-related directives). It's very mysterious and very annoying.

I hope this might save someone else from tearing their hair out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in some files.

After removing all inline tailwind classes and putting them in CSS files with `@apply` it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this.
I think, my main problem was 'missing postcss file config' because I do tailwind initialization with `npx tailwind init`, not `npx tailwind init -p` (which also generate postcss fileconfig).

Comment: Exactly what happened to me when I started to follow the regular Installation guide https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation the switched to the one for NextJS https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution so that you can fix the problem in next js is this**

in the tailwind.config.js add this configuration:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  subject: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/typography"),require('@tailwindcss/forms'),],
  
};
```

**and in postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['tailwindcss','postcss-preset-env'],
};
```

**lastly in the next js config you will add this to make it work for you**.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  swcMinify: true,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    concurrentFeatures: false, // <- Set this option to false.
    serverComponents: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

and you need creating in styles  and adding the style in global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind components;
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything in this question, what worked was updating nextjs:

> npm install next@latest

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything for 2 hours, just running:

```
npm i tailwindcss@3.0.0
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

for me what was wrong that I unknowingly put spaces in regex. so my code became-

```
content: [
"./pages/**/*.{ js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
"./components/**/*.{ js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
],
```

and this was what causing error. so I again copy pasted from official website.
to make it look like

```
content: [
"./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
],
```

I know it was a silly mistake but sometimes you do it unintentionally. :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for 3 days. Turns out the main css file was called `globals.css` instead of `globals.scss`. You must use SASS instead of regular CSS because the `@tailwind` annotation only works in SASS.

Answer (score 1):

In _app.js add this line :

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
```

Replace code of tailwind.config.js with this :

```
`module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};`
```

Answer (score 1):

I just passed from `Pages Router` router to `App Router`.

In `Pages Router` Tailwindcss was asking to add this directive in tailwind.config.js when working on a NextJs project: `important: "#__next"` because the root node from the Nextjs app had an id of `__next`.

Please consider removing the `important` directive, from `tailwind.config.js` when working on NextJs `App Router`.

Answer (score 0):

###### postcss.config.js

---

```js
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    }
```

###### tailwind.config.js

---

```
    module.exports = {
      mode: 'jit',
      content: [
        "./**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

###### global.css

---

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: This is what worked for me, thanks! I was missing a postcss settings file and specifying the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this too, but my solution was to edit the tailwind.connfig.js

Depending with the version

**For version 2**

```
module.exports = {
 purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
 theme: {
   extend: {},
 },
 variants: {
   extend: {},
 },
 plugins: [],
}
```

**For version 3**

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './containers/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

<!-- You have to add paths to folders in which you are using 
   tailwindcss in the tailwind.config.js file -->

<!-- Example: I add './containers/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' to the "content"-->
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple potential cause is a misspelt components / pages folder - make sure they're spelt correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have just re-installed my Next.js project and went with Tailwind's guide and it worked!

Documentation: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I did not follow the set up steps properly. I forgot to run `npx tailwind init` which was the cause of my troubles. I created the `tailwind.config.js` but forgot to create proper `postcss.config.js`.

P/S: Make sure the content is pointing to the files you want covered, if its pointing to `pages` and `components` while you are using `src` file structure, tailwind will not work,

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official guide to install Tailwind.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

If it still doesn't work, delete *node_modules* and *package-lock.json*, then run

```
npm i
```

again.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is migrating to Tailwind from another UI library like UIkit, make sure all the previous css file imports are removed from _app.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use tailwind because the folder name contains "[ ]". I fixed the problem by simplifying the folder name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mine was created using create-next-app and i was missing a `<main>` tag in my page function.

Answer (score 0):

In my next project styles were not applied only in  `src/pages` directory. So I just hardcoded and added to every page.

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
```

None of the above solutions not worked except this:

```
// src/pages/about.tsx
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
```

Answer (score -1):

Now it is by default supported by `create-next-app`

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

On installation, you'll see the following prompts

```
What is your project named? my-app
Would you like to use TypeScript? No / Yes
Would you like to use ESLint? No / Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? No / Yes
Would you like to use `src/` directory? No / Yes
Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) No / Yes
Would you like to customize the default import alias? No / Yes
```

Use **Yes** for **tailwind CSS**