# Tailwind CSS not Working with vite React - after installing react router

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I have done some basic setup to test the react router,
installed and configured tailwind as per documentation
but it isn't working

i think problem is mainly caused after react router implementation

please check following repository for code

https://github.com/AmitMali/react-router-demo

rechecked all the documentation and implementation

Comment: You may need to add your `/public` folder to the `content`-section of the tailwind config

Comment: I found a solution on different thread , https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537329/4429024

Answer (score 1):

You need a `css` file with

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```